# PDF Converting Part Numbers to Links

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe, ghostscript

I have a very large PDF catalog with over 50K part numbers in it.  Would like to script out a process to turn the part numbers into clickable links.  Have been peeking around with Acrobat, iTextSharp, PDFSharp and a few others, but cant seem to see if anything like that has been done before?

Will I need to manually update each link, or is there some hope of automating this process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This task can be easily accomplished using [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/).

The library can retrieve all words from a page with their bounding rectangles. Also, the library can create hyperlinks at specified locations of a PDF page.

Here is a short sample for your task. The following code opens specified file, finds all words that start with L and "turn" these words into links.

```
public static void makeWordsHyperlinks(string file, string outputFile)
{
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(file))
    {
        foreach (PdfPage page in pdf.Pages)
        {
            PdfCollection<PdfTextData> words = page.GetWords();
            foreach (PdfTextData word in words)
            {
                // let's take anything starting from L
                // you can discriminate words as you like, of course
                if (word.Text.StartsWith("L", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    // build lookup query. you can use any url, of course
                    string lookupUrl = string.Format(@"https://www.google.ru/#q={0}", word.Text);

                    // let's draw rectangle around word.
                    // just to make links easier to find
                    page.Canvas.DrawRectangle(word.Bounds, PdfDrawMode.Stroke);

                    page.AddHyperlink(word.Bounds, new Uri(lookupUrl));
                }
            }
        }

        pdf.Save(outputFile);
    }
}
```

I assume that your part numbers are something like XXX-YYYYY. If your part numbers consist of several words then task is a bit harder. You will need to combine words and their bounding rectangles.

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.